# Inserting smilies into div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, emoticons

I'm working on some small chat application. I want to implement smilies over there so when i click on some smiley it will appear in textarea where user enters his message and when user clicks on select i want smilies to appear in div that contains the conversation.

After some workarounds i got to idea that replacing textarea with div contenteditable="true"
doesn't work that well so i did wrap certain smiley name with ':' like :wink: in textarea but still i need to replace :wink: with real span containing image as background.

Problem is i don't see a way to make this dynamically but doing each one by one.

for example:

```
        if ($('.line:contains(":wink:")').length > 0) {
            var oldLineHTML = $('.line:contains(":wink:")').html();
            $('.line:contains(":wink:")').html(oldLineHTML.replace(/:wink:/gi, '<span class="wink></span>"'));
```

I have plenty of smilies so doing this very resource expensive function will costs me much and also will cause me lots of problems during maintenance.

How can i do that dynamically? Or maybe you have better solution which will require to re-design... I'm up to it if it is required.

thanks
            }

Comment: Are you doing this operation on page load or when they enter the text?

Comment: Also, you mention that you want to replace the wink in a textarea.  I don't think that you can put html and have it rendered (aka not plain text) inside of a textarea.

Comment: @hivie7510, i don't images appear in chatbox div only. What i meant that i had no luck working with <div contenteditable="true"></div> instead of textarea which messed CSS inside of this div so much so i threw it away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var testString = "test1 :smile: test2 :wink:";
alert(testString.replace(/:([^:]*):/g, '<span class="$1"></span>'));
```

Comment: that's what i'm talking about! +1 for you :)

Comment: How is that any different from the code that he has presented in his question?  Isn't $('.line:contains(":wink:")').html(oldLineHTML.replace(/:wink:/gi, '<span class="wink></span>"'));    the same as testString.replace(/:([^:]*):/g, '<span class="$1"></span>').  I guess that there is a dynamic about this because it doesn't care about the wink, just the content between the ::'s.

Comment: @hivie7510: Indeed. His problem was that he had to search for the exact string, and replace the exact string with a static pre-defined string, which is harder to maintain when you get a lot of smilies.

Comment: Thanks Dvir, will try that out,,, seems like what i was looking for because never wanted to mess with array of smilies and Regular Expressions are far beyond my comprehension level.

Comment: @hivie7510 with @Dvir's post i don't need to check if div contains anything but just to apply Regular Expression. Of course there will be some waste in div's where there is no :somesmilie: while scanning it with replace() but still it is much easier to maintain.

Comment: @Dvir Azulay, i still have one problem on output it shows me <span></span> instead of showing rendered tag

Comment: @eugeneK: בבקשה :), how are you placing back the HTML into the div after the replace?

Comment: I'm using jQuery.tmpl()... ${body} supposed to be HTML but after some checks i've done this ain't got nothing to do with your script, which does exactly what it needed. This is .template() issue so i've asked new question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is read every string that is wrapped by colons `:[something]:`, then convert it into span. So that you don't have to define every smile, and it is easy to maintain.

Comment: It looks like that is what he is doing with the :wink:

Comment: It will replace only `:wink:` smile. He has plenty of smilies and he wants to avoid making many cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this on page load, then you can do this in a $(document).ready().  Then you can use selector that you have $('.line:contains(":wink:")') and use the $each operator to loop over each one and perform the update.  This will cover you for the page load.  But if you refactor that $each code into a method, then you can call it each time the text is updated.  I think this will give you the best in both cases.  Something like this:

```
function replaceWinks(){
$('.line:contains(":wink:")').each(function(index) {
    //Replace the wink here
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
replaceWinks();
});
```

I would recommend replacing the winks server side for the page load though.  It will be more performant.  Also it will avoid content that changes when after the first view.

Comment: I'm using chat with no page reloads and i want to sent as less as possible data via json. I think server to convert :wink: to <span class="wink"></span> will take more time than using inline jQuery... Thanks for input though/

Answer (score 0):

Jeaffrey Gilbert's idea is good, but I have another one that may be interesting:
write down you winks the way you want(let's say **[SmileName]**), and when processing the text with jquery, read every one of them, and replace the `[` with `<div class="` then replace the `]` sign, with `"></div>`, this way, you will end up like this:

using these smilies:

1- [smile]

2- [wink]

3- [shy]

will lead to the following markup

1- `<div class="smile"></div>`

2- `<div class="wink"></div>`

3- `<div class="shy"></div>`

and using CSS, you will give every class of them, a different background image, which is the smile image.

by utilizing this method, every div will lead to displaying your smilies, and you will write the code once, and end up using it wherever you want, without repeating yourself

Comment: for emoticon (esp. in a forum), it is familiar to use colons as its wrapper.

Comment: He is effectively doing that now, he is replacing :wink: with the span whose class is wink.